# StreamWriter does throw exception underlying connection is broken?

Tags: c#, tcp, connection, streamwriter

I am using `StreamWriter` instantiated over a `Tcpstream` 
like this

```
streamWriter = new StreamWriter(tcpClient.GetStream());
```

I am confused about the behavior of following calls with regards to Exceptions. The following two functions are expected to raise `IOException` Surprisingly they do not raise the `IOException` when the server to which the `tcpClient` is connected is disconnected and therefore the underlying TCP client connection is broken..  These two lines execute without raising any Exception. Why ?

```
streamWriter.WriteLine(strBuffer);
streamWriter.Flush();
```

EDIT: This particular post also helped me understand the reason, besides the replies here from the experts.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/netfxnetcom/thread/b177a935-7430-4812-9555-f747748df1af
In essence the NetworkStream.Write is called when WriteLine of StreamWriter is called, This writes to the out-going buffer and returns, without blocking, unless if the buffer was full. The internal buffer maintained by OS contains unsent data, which OS will keep trying to send until a given number of attempts fail.
WriteLine will throw IOException but not necessarily every time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is unrelated to `StreamWriter`, it's only about the behavior of `NetworkStream`.

`NetworkStream.Flush()` is a no-op. In particular is does not block until the recipient has acknowledged all bytes sent prior to the flush.

> The Flush method implements the Stream.Flush method; however, because NetworkStream is not buffered, it has no affect on network streams. Calling the Flush method does not throw an exception.

*(from [NetworkStream.Flush Method (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.flush.aspx))*

You will get your exception at some point, but that can be much later. Essentially neither `NetworkStream` nor the OS know that the TCP connection is already broken, so they won't raise an exception.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something.. but I've traced this and it appears that NetworkStream's Write method doesn't ever raise these exceptions. Once it calls the native socket send method it literally does nothing if it returns -1. It just sets some private member variables afterwards..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I'd expect `NetworkStream.Write` to forward to `Socket.Send` which throws a `SocketException` on error. Since the documentation for `NetworkStream.Write` does not include that exception, `NetworkStream.Write` probably catches it, and throws an `IOException` instead.

Comment: Sorry yeah.. it forwards it to Socket's Send method.. which does what I describe above (it calls `send` in `ws2_32.dll`).

Comment: @CodesInChaos thanks and what about streamWriter.WriteLine ? it does'nt raise any exception either, should it not be calling NetworkStream's write method ? which according to docs is a blocking method and raise IOException too.. ?

Comment: @Jane Blocking in this context means that it blocks if the send buffer is full. It doesn't mean that it blocks until the other side received the data.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Sorry for my misunderstanding but I was referring to this from the docs of NetworkStream.Write The Write method blocks until the requested number of bytes is sent or a SocketException is thrown. So regardless of other side receiving data, I would assume it throws an exception , which is perhaps internally swallowed by writeLine of StreamWriter ?

Comment: @Jane The documentation is badly worded. "sent" means being written into the send buffer, and not actually being sent over the wire(or even acknowledged). You will get the exception at some point, perhaps at a later `Read`/`Write` operation, or at the latest when `Close`ing the stream.

Answer (score 1):

This is a core aspect of TCP, a protocol that promises a reliable transfer of data to another machine across a network.  It is the operating system's job to ensure that the data actually ends up at the other machine.  It will attempt to get the data across many times, long after you've written the data, resending IP packets if necessary if it doesn't get an acknowledgement for them.  Which will be the case when you disconnected the machine.  It will not give up on doing so after re-trying it many times.  It can be as long as a minute before it gives up.

What is implicit in this contract that the connection is considered reliable at your end.  Anything you write ends up in a *buffer*, located in the kernel memory pool.  This buffer greatly enhances the throughput for your program, taking up the slack between your program and a variable transmission rate.  Once it is in the buffer, it the operating system's duty to ensure that data actually gets sent.

You can see where this goes, you don't get an exception from a disconnect until later.  It could happen on any subsequent Write() attempt, when the buffer gets too full.  It may be delayed all the way to you calling the socket's Close() method.